# Is there a halachic requirement that requires Mincha be said at the Chosson's tisch?

Tags: wedding, mincha-afternoon-prayer

If I correctly recall, Gemarrah Brachot states that the Chatan is exempt from davening at the time of the chasseneh (or is this specifically for Ma'ariv)?

I have heard of several situations where the wedding was scheduled close to but just before twilight, so the ketubah was written for a specific date. At the last minute, the people at the chosson's tisch insisted on davening mincha. When mincha ended, it was already twilight and they had to wait until nightfall and rewrite the date on the ketubah to the next day. The delay caused inconvenience to all the other waiting guests and really infuriated the hosts who had to pay overtime to the caterer and the musicians. This doesn't sound right to me. Is there an absolute requirement that mincha must be done at the tisch, or couldn't people have assembled a minyan in another room without involving the chosson and their family?

Answer (score 2):

The groom is exempt from certain mitzvot aseh from the time of the wedding until he consummates the marriage. He is not exempt from anything before the wedding occurs.

There is obviously no requirement for minchah to be said at a tisch, especially as there is no guarantee that the tisch will be at a time when minchah can be said. (Morning weddings in the summer, night weddings in the winter, etc.) Now it's obviously nice to have a minyan because there will be a bunch of people in the same place who haven't davened. Also it is traditional for the groom to add the vidui to his shemoneh esreh.

Your situation sounds more like a case of bad planning - my guess is whoever was planning the timing didn't consider davening, and the people who wanted to daven didn't consider the timing of the wedding.

Comment: "Also it is traditional for the groom to add the vidui to his shemoneh esreh." I don't understand what you are trying to show with this sentence

Comment: @DoubleAA often the choson will daven separately (and earlier) so that his extra time will not hold up the minyon and also so that there will be no problem with timing at the tisch. At the wedding of one of my sons a group of people started davening ma'ariv in front of the stairs from the second floor of the hall (where the yichud room was) so that the choson and kallah could not get down to join everyone. Some people just do not think.

Comment: @sabbahillel I know all of that (except your story, where the Mesader Kiddushin should have told them all to move out of the way), but that doesn't seem to be what the OP was trying to say.

Comment: @DoubleAA I was trying to give a specific example (chatan and his viduy) to back up the general principle stated in the previous sentence (it's obviously nice to say minchah). Sorry if I didn't explain myself clearly.